# Power method Matlab

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab

I am trying to find the largest eigenvalue and its corresponding eigenvector by the

> [Power method](http://www.prenhall.com/bretscher1e/html/proj10.html)

..
I did this code and I just want to display the largest eigenvalue and its eigenvector after asking the user to enter an n * n matrix.. can someone help me to add the right statements?
Here is my code..

```
function [ v d] = power_method( A )

disp ( ' Enter the matrix whose eigen value is to be found')

% Calling matrix A

A = input ( ' Enter matrix A : \n')
% check for matrix A

% it should be a square matrix

[na , ma ] = size (A);
if na ~= ma
disp('ERROR:Matrix A should be a square matrix')
return
end

%display of final result

fprintf (' The largest eigen value obtained is \n')
disp('and the corresponding eigen vector is ')
```

Comment: Initialize v randomly and then iterate  v = A * v; v = v / norm(v); until convergence.

Comment: Note that power iteration doesn't necessarily find eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong in the code, can you show me how please

Comment: Do you necessarily want to use power iteration to find an eigenvector?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding of the problem.